# How to avoid creating schema with PlayFramework

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have an existing database schema managed by another webapp. The playframework I am creating needs to read/write to this existing schema but it's deleting and recreating the tables when play starts up.

How do I turn off the table creation?

update:

- play 1.2.5
- mysql

update2:

```
@Entity(name="mytable_name")
public class Sample extends Model {    
   public Integer some_value;
   public String fullname;
}
```

inside a Controller method...

```
List<Sample> list = Sample.findAll();
```

The table exists with data, I run "play test", hit the controller method that calls findAll, and the table is dropped, recreated, and now empty.

The schemas do not match perfectly in data types with text fields being different sizes. I was expecting query errors but not this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Play 1.x with JPA you can put this line in your application.conf

```
jpa.ddl=none
```

Comment: I tried that but sadly, it did not change the outcome. It still drops the table and all its contents, then creates it again, empty. It does that after a call to findAll()

Comment: @darren: did you disabled evolutions as I suggested in other answer ?

Comment: you are running your app in test mode so be sure you don't have a setting like %test.jpa.ddl=..." and be sure you don't have some "Fixtures.deleteDatabase()" in a @Before method in your test. Another point, if you are in test mode, use a specific database in this mode that can be deleted

Comment: Yes, all good points and all things I checked too. I did just run it in production mode and it reported a query error on the query but did not destroy the table. It seems play will recreate the schedule no matter what the setting in dev mode. Unfortunately, that will make this task more difficult to test.

Comment: play does not recreate the schema in dev mode unless you specify it, you must have some directive in your config that specify this

Comment: FOUND IT! It was hidden in the middle of the %test statements. I missed it thinking they were commented out. The generated configuration has %test.jpa.ddl=create at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 2):

From official [evolutions' documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/evolutions):

> Evolutions are automatically activated if a database is configured in
>   application.conf and evolution scripts are present. You can disable
>   them by setting [evolutions.enabled](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/configuration#evolutions.enabled) to false. For example when tests
>   set up their own database you can disable evolutions for the test
>   environment.

Comment: does it 2.0? if yes how to disable evolutions it?

Comment: @gaurav this is Play 1 sample, for Play 2 check its docs: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Evolutions | you need to uncomment this line in your application.conf file: `evolutionplugin=disabled` | next time write in separate question