# Using playframework 1.2.5 with an existing database

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am trying to fetch some data from the Oracle 10g DB. So I aded the db related details in the application.conf file, when I start the server then in the command prompt it shows that the connection is successful.

I created an Entity class, a table similar to the class name is present in the database.

```
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("select * from Emp");
    List<Emp> empList = query.getResultList();
    for(Emp employees : empList)
        System.out.println(employees.emp_name);
```

I am getting the below exception when I try to run the code:

`IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from models.Emp]`

**Edit:**

If i change the code to this:

```
List<Emp> empList = Emp.all().fetch();
    for(Emp employees : empList)
        System.out.println(employees.emp_name);
```

Then I am getting an exception:

`JPAQueryException occured : Error while executing query from models.Emp: ORA-00904: "EMP0_"."ID": invalid identifier`

This is my model class named Emp.java:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Emp extends Model {

@Id
@Column(name="Emp_Id")
public Integer id;
public String emp_name;
public Integer dept_id;
public Integer age;
public String sex;

}
```

This is the `emp` table present in the Oracle DB with some data:

```
EMP_ID  NUMBER. EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(20), DEPT_ID NUMBER, AGE NUMBER, SEX VARCHAR2(6)
```

I have rephrased the heading of this thread since I was not aware of the reason for this problem.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a:
    `List<Emp> empList = Emp.findAll();`

But I dont think this is the actual problem. The problem lies somewhere in the mapping to the db tables. Your error message:

```
`JPAQueryException occured : Error while executing query from models.Emp: ORA-00904:        "EMP0_"."ID": invalid identifier`
```

implies that the actual query tries to fetch column "ID" instead of the actual column you want (according to your annotation,`@Column(name="Emp_Id")`).

The annotation does not work as you expect. Maybe problem with uppercase/lowercase charaters?

Edited response:

Your model class EMP inherits from the playframework parent Model class which generates the unique identifier id. This is probably causing your problems.

Comment: I changed the model class to `@Id public Integer emp_id;` but still the same problem :( I am not sure why the `Emp_Id` is becoming `"EMP0_"."ID"` as shown in the error message. Also, regarding the case sensitivity issue, SQL queries table names and column names are not case sensitive right?

Comment: Hmm, all model classes in playframework inherits from a class Model which has the ID field. Since that class handles the primary key, you don´t have to have the emp_id in your model object. BTW. Are you working against an existing database table or are you letting play/hibernate generate them for you?

Comment: I am having an existing table named "Emp" in the Oracle DB. From the existing table only I am trying to fetch the values. I dont want play/hibernate to generate any table. While running the above code, I saw some alter query is fired against the DB...don't know why :( Please help

Comment: Have you looked at the `play.db.jpa.GenericModel` that togheter with stuff discussed in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626004/how-to-avoid-creating-schema-with-playframework would probably help you to work against an existing db.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it did not worked. I added this line: `jpa.ddl=none`, `evolutionplugin=disabled` and commented out the line `%test.jpa.ddl=create` but still it did not worked. Apart from these entries, I have the db configuration details in the file. But I dont have the `jpa.dialect` and `jpa.debugSQL` set, these are commented out. Any help on this please?

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas for the moment, but I would recommend you to rephrase the question to something like "Using playframework with an existing database" or similar so it reflects the actual problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi, I got the solution in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/EuY0y_b5G-M Thanks for pointing me to the right direction (i.e. using GenericModel)

Answer (score 1):

The play way to do this is

```
List<Emp> empList = Emp.all().fetch();
```

Comment: I am trying to fetch details from an existing table (maintained by some other application), I got the above exception. Please let me know how to resolve this :(

Comment: I see you found the answer to the database mapping problem by using GenericModel.  You changed the question - your original problem was an issue with your query - which I answered.  The second question relates to not understanding that the Model class in Play comes with a hard-coded id field.  Glad you got it working anyway.